# storage permission buildozer android 11

Tags: python, android, kivy

i am doing a app for android using kivy

> i have done this:-

**in main.py**

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

**in Buildozer**

```
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

But the thing is that in android 11 or android 10 storage permission are changed

i know that we can apt-out in android 10 but i want in also 11

Comment: Please tell how to 'apt-out' on 10.

Comment: @blackapps requestLegacyExternalStorage set to True in mainfest

Comment: For Android 11 you dont have to do anything special. Just write your files as you used to do.

Comment: @blackapps do you know how to edit mainfest of apk?

Comment: iam getting error on editing mainfest using apk aditor

Comment: These permissions simply don't do anything if you target android 11+. For now you can still target api 29 and use the opt-out.

Comment: @inclement then how to get storage permission from android 11 +

Comment: For the most part you don't, Android really wants you to use the java api calls instead of the filesystem. There's a new permission (maybe not available yet, can't remember) to get full filesystem access, but I think its use is restricted if you want to put the app on the Play store.